# How can I use the Win32 toolbar standard bitmaps outside of a toolbar?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

The Win32 API provides a standard toolbar control and you can use standard bitmaps to differentiate the buttons.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/toolbar-standard-button-image-index-values

How can I use these standard icons outside of a toolbar? Or maybe, are there other standard icons with a file, a folder, etc?

Comment: From the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/toolbar-standard-button-image-index-values) you pasted: *"You use these values to specify an image index within a standard image list that was loaded with the `TB_LOADIMAGES` message."* As for a replacement: New applications use vector graphics in place of raster images. The [Segoe MDL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font) font is the standard resource.

Comment: But I still can't find a way to access those standard image lists, when you send a TB_LOADIMAGES the toolbar knows how to access them, sure.

Comment: [TB_GETIMAGELIST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tb-getimagelist).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so thanks to IInspectable I looked into using TB_GETIMAGELIST to get a handle to the image list that the toolbar uses and with

[ImageList_GetIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-imagelist_geticon)

you can get an HICON from the imagelist and an index.